# How do I install and run a TFTP server?

Tags: tftp

I have an embedded VxWorks target that needs to boot its kernel from my Ubuntu computer. How do I install and run a TFTP server?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

#### TFTP Server Install and Setup

1. Install following packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp
   ```
2. Create /etc/xinetd.d/tftp and put this entry

   ```
   service tftp
   {
   protocol        = udp
   port            = 69
   socket_type     = dgram
   wait            = yes
   user            = nobody
   server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
   server_args     = /tftpboot
   disable         = no
   }
   ```
3. Create a folder /tftpboot  this should match whatever you gave in server_args. mostly it will be tftpboot

   ```
   sudo mkdir /tftpboot
   sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot
   sudo chown -R nobody /tftpboot
   ```
4. Restart the xinetd service.

   newer systems:

   ```
   sudo service xinetd restart
   ```

   older systems:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
   ```

Now our tftp server is up and running.

#### Testing our tftp server

5. Create a file named test with some content in /tftpboot path of the tftp server

   Obtain the ip address of the tftp server using ifconfig command
6. Now in some other system follow the following steps.

   ```
   tftp 192.168.1.2
   tftp> get test
   Sent 159 bytes in 0.0 seconds

   tftp> quit

   cat test
   ```

Source:
http://mohammadthalif.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/installing-and-testing-tftpd-in-ubuntudebian/

Comment: this doesnt work for 13.04. I just tried

Comment: only step 4 needs to be changed, since xinetd is spawned by upstart. you need to restart it with 'service xinetd restart'

Comment: I followed this instruction and faced permission denied! Destination filename [c2950-i6q4l2-mz.121-22.EA1b.bin]? 
TFTP: error code 2 received - Access violation

%Error opening tftp://10.1.11.14/c2950-i6q4l2-mz.121-22.EA1b.bin (Permission denied)
#copy flash:c2950-i6q4l2-mz.121-22.EA1b.bin tftp:
Address or name of remote host []? 10.1.11.14
Destination filename [c2950-i6q4l2-mz.121-22.EA1b.bin]? 
TFTP: error code 2 received - Access violation

Comment: @Mohammad Rafiee: the blog post linked to here added some info: run `sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot` between step 1 and 2 of "Testing our tftp server". Not that it helped me, but it looks like it helped others.

Comment: On 14.04, this did not work for me. The info about `/tftpboot` in `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp` did not seem to matter. Instead, the client looks in the directory `/srv/tftp` as specified in `/etc/inetd.conf`. I don't if the way things are setup changed since the article, or if I screwed up somehow. If the answer above does not work for you, try putting your test file in `/srv/tftp` instead.

Comment: The only way I found that actually worked was to `touch` a file with the filename I was about to put. Check this page as well: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=841766

Comment: I followed the steps as is but it didn't work for me until i edited  `/etc/inetd.conf` and commented out `tftp           dgram   udp     wait    nobody /usr/sbin/tcpd /usr/sbin/in.tftpd --tftpd-timeout 300 --retry-timeout 5 --mcast-port 1758 --mcast-addr 239.239.239.0-255 --mcast-$`

using a #

Comment: How is possible for user nobody to use privileged port 69?

Comment: @elbarna user:nobody can have access to this service.  
xinetd - which runs the service - has elevated access.  
BTW it was working exactly as it was written Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Please note that with Ubuntu 16.04, you will experience `error code 2 (access violation)` . To fix it put `tftpboot -s` in `server_args` (no leading slash, `-s` at the end. Source: https://icesquare.com/wordpress/solvedtftp-error-code-2-access-violation/

Comment: @CharlesB      tftpboot -s in server_args     This also fixed for me on Ubuntu 18 Thanks!

Comment: This answer needs to be updated with "tftpboot -s" and a command to set permissions to 0755 (or similar) on any file placed in /tftpboot (e.g. $ sudo chmod 0755 /tftpboot/my-file).

Answer (score 9):

You can install [`atftpd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/atftpd) and it will create a directory called `/tftpboot` in which you may place your files. Put especially the `pxelinux.0` file there. Any future configuration will be addressed if it is necessary.

When you install the package with

```
sudo apt-get install atftpd
```

it will use Debconf to prompt you for some choices. You can set many choices(server timeout may be useful), especially the **basepath**. You can also adjust the multicast range.

Comment: What is pxelinux.0 for?  I'm booting a VxWorks target, so I thought that I only need the file vxworks in /tftpboot.

Comment: Sorry - that did not work for me.

Comment: Try renaming `vxworks` to `pxelinux.0`, just to see whether my answer will work for future users.

Comment: this doesnt work for 13.04. I just tried

Comment: @BЈовић This is somewhat of an old answer and I honestly do not know the procedure for 13.04.

Comment: The default location for files with atftpd is now /src/tftp.

Answer (score 9):

You can install `tftpd-hpa` and change the configurations . Steps for installing tftpd-hpa is explained in this [blog post](http://irfantechinfo.blogspot.in/2013/09/installing-tftp-server-on-ubuntu-1004.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: upvoted you only because tftpd-hpa is a stupid simple tftp server to use and doesn't actually require any of the config needed in that post just drop your files in /var/lib/tftpboot and you are set (on ubuntu 16.04 not sure about other OS).