# How to install and configure a TFTP server on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, tftp

I've been trying to build a TFTP server on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 build for a number of weeks using articles that I've found on-line, but all my attempts seem to fail as the TFTP server that I've installed seems not to be responding.  It doesn't matter if I GET or PUT, I always get a timeout error.

The most recent articles that I've tried are:

- [How do I install and run a TFTP server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201505/how-do-i-install-and-run-a-tftp-server)
- http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/100006-install-and-configure-tftp-under-ubuntu-14-04

Both of these have been unsuccessful, each time with the TFTP client complaining of a timeout error.

I've added (or at least I think I have) rules to the UFW and iptables to allow access to UDP port 69, but without any success.

I have been building my base Ubuntu 14.04 OS from the mini.iso file I've downloaded from the Ubuntu download pages on to a VirtualBox VM (ver 4.3.8 r92456) running on my Win7 pro machine.  No additional packages were installed during the initial build, but I have installed SSH and NTP (both of which appear to be working) post initial build. The TFTP client is running from my Win7 machine and the Ubuntu machine has a static IP address.

---

The connection is being made from a remote TFTP client on my Win7 machine.

```
$ netstat -apu
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 *:tftp                  *:*                                 8166/xinetd
udp        0      0 test.paumaz.local:ntp   *:*                                 1332/ntpd
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*                                 1332/ntpd
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*                                 1332/ntpd
udp6       0      0 fe80::250:56ff:febe:ntp [::]:*                              1332/ntpd
udp6       0      0 localhost:ntp           [::]:*                              1332/ntpd
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*                              1332/ntpd

$ netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 *:tftp                  *:*
udp        0      0 test.paumz.local:ntp    *:*
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*
udp6       0      0 fe80::250:56ff:febe:ntp [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:ntp           [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7010     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7559     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     7370     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9458     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9209     /var/run/acpid.socket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the same problem here.
Old Ubuntu 9.? that has upgraded to 14.04 by clicking "Yes".
User is defined from "before" (default everything).

I've found it to work with:

```
tftp AAA.DDD.DDD.RRR  
get test  
^D  

cat test
```

This works, where `AAA.DDD.DDD.RRR` is the actual IP of my own machine.
(I currently have a static local offline net, so eg: `tftp 192.168.1.1` is given as command)
Replacing this numeric address with the word "localhost" ==> Timeout at "get"
(it seems to connect ok, but it can't get the files).

Comment: Sorry: This "answer" should have been a comment on the previous answer... /Göran

Answer (score 9):

Install following packages.

`sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp`

Create `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp`

`sudo nano /etc/xinetd.d/tftp`

and put this entry

```
service tftp
{
protocol        = udp
port            = 69
socket_type     = dgram
wait            = yes
user            = nobody
server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args     = /tftpboot
disable         = no
}
```

Create a folder `/tftpboot` this should match whatever you gave in `server_args`. mostly it will be tftpboot

```
sudo mkdir /tftpboot
sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot
sudo chown -R nobody /tftpboot
```

Restart the `xinetd` service.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

You must allow `udp port 69` in firewall.

Edit 1

[image]

Like I say, first `tftp localhost`, then `get ...`.

Give output `cat /var/log/syslog | grep tftp`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is similar (if not the same) as one of the articles that I had tried but was unable to get working.

Comment: Do you try connect from server to localhost `tftp localhost` ? If you you in this case have timeout, server not work. What say command `netstat -apu`?

Comment: Tried running the tftp client from the local Ubuntu machine using the command "get localhost:filename" and this also gives a timeout error.

Comment: Try first `tftp localhost` if connection be successful, then type `get filename`. My tftp server works but command `get localhost:filename` don't work.

Comment: Tried the "get filename" and this also times out.

Comment: Pelase give me output from `sudo service xinetd status` if you are used my manual for instalation and use `xinetd`

Comment: I have now completely rebuilt my Ubuntu server from the ground up, using the above script and still I get a timeout error.  The output from the "service xinetd status" is # service xinetd status
xinetd start/running, process 1833

Comment: I edit answer, look.

Comment: Did you check the syslog for messages?