# How to setup a tftp server in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, tftp

I am trying to setup a tftp server on my computer, without success.

I've tried following both [this](http://irfantechinfo.blogspot.in/2013/09/installing-tftp-server-on-ubuntu-1004.html) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201505/how-do-i-install-and-run-a-tftp-server) guide without success

```
$ sudo tftp localhost
tftp> get pippo.txt
Transfer timed out.
```

Comment: using the xinetd.d/tftp file suggested [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=191865) it worked

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are sending the file from the current directory. And one more thing you can check is edit the tftp service file in **/etc/xinetd.d/tftp**

make the setting like this

```
service tftp
{
   protocol = udp
   port = 69
   socket_type = dgram
   wait = yes
   user = nobody
   server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
   server_args = /tftpboot -s
   disable = no
}
```