# where to find the tftp installed server in ubuntu

Tags: tftp

I have installed the tftp server on Ubuntu, and in certain point it asks me to create a file test on tftp server and also to obtain the ip of the server.
Where can I find the tftp server I have already installed?

I have followed instructions on this site:
[How do I install and run a TFTP server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201505/how-do-i-install-and-run-a-tftp-server)

Comment: Did you create the folder here: `server_args     = /tftpboot`, the `/tftpboot`  should be the location?

Comment: WElcome to askubuntu! Was there something confusing [here?](http://askubuntu.com/a/202548/225694)

Answer (score 1):

Since you installed `tftp` via the packaging system (good newbie), you can ask the packaging system where the files are via:

```
dpkg -L xinetd  
dpkg -L tftpd
dpkg -L tftp
```